# How do I customize a DaisyUI theme in Tailwind using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, daisyui

I would like to customize an existing DaisyUI theme within my tailwind.config.ts file.
I am using Next.js.

On the DaisyUI page there is the documentation for JavaScript only ([text](https://daisyui.com/docs/themes/).
And all other examples I could find where in JavaScript as well.

Here is my tailwind.config.ts (as an example, I would like to base my theme on the retro theme):

```
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
  daisyui: {
    themes: [
      {
        mytheme: {
          ...require("daisyui")['[data-theme=retro]'],
          primary: "magenta",
          ".btn": {
            "border-radius": "0px",
          }
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  // needs to be after custom theme declaration above?
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
}
export default config
```

And here is my Next.js main page layout.tsx (I declared mytheme as the DaisyUI data-theme):

```
import './globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Title',
  description: 'Descr.',
}

export default function RootLayout(
  { children, }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" data-theme="mytheme">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <div className='btn btn-primary'>Button</div>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

What I see is this:
[image: My result]

So I can see that the custom color and border-radius are working,
BUT it is not based on the retro theme, otherwise the background would of the color as seen below.

This is what the unchanged retro theme looks like:
[image: Retro Theme]

I know I maybe can change properties of single classes like .btn, ... with @apply in CSS, but I would like to do it at one place for all elements in the tailwind config.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, try to `import` instead of `require` daisyui.
See this example!

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";
import daisyui from "daisyui";
import typography from "@tailwindcss/typography";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic": "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [typography, daisyui],
  daisyui: {
    themes: [
      {
        mytheme: {
          // You should define your custom theme here
          // If you want to extend from an existing DaisyUI theme, use extend instead of the spread operator
          extend: {
            "theme": "retro",
            "primary": "magenta",
          },
          // You should define your custom styles for .btn like this
          "btn": {
            "border-radius": "1px",
            "border-width": "10px",
            "color": "yellow",
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};

export default config;
```

Comment: Importing  daisyui at the top like you did here works, but then ```...daisyui["data-theme=retro"]``` throws ``Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"data-theme=retro"' can't be used to index type '{ handler: PluginCreator; config?: Partial<Config> | undefined; }'.
  Property 'data-theme=retro' does not exist on type '{ handler: PluginCreator; config?: Partial<Config> | undefined; }'.``

Comment: Please see my updated answer, and accept if you like it